# How to automatically update svn after commit

Tags: svn, subversive

I know how to make automatic update on the local working copy, but what if the working copy is in the different hosts?

Is any way to have automatic update with SSH?

Answer (score 3):

Post-commit hook can execute **any** action (and ssh to another host with executing in session `svn up` - too)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, TortoiseSVN supports this functionality.

Comment: Comment is offtopic since the question explicitly asks for a SSH solution.

Comment: @BorislavSabev - your comment is offtopic, because a) TortoiseSVN have **client-side post-commit hooks** b) in own hook it can connect (using putty, f.e) to remote host and update WC on this host and this way doesn't depend from repository-side hooks

Comment: @LazyBadger I am aware of client-side TortoiseSVN hooks but since it seems that the question is for a server-side solution something like "If you were using this and that on that OS" doesn't seem to help a lot, does it?

Comment: @BorislavSabev - for me question *doesn't* seem as "server-side solution" (subversive tag). But I hardly translated question into real question anyway and "as asked so answered"